# How can I get Client ip in NGINX when the request is routed from a stream block

Tags: nginx, networking

I have a specific usecase where i need my request to go from the stream block to the http block.

This is the same configuration on the same machine.

it looks something like this

```
stream {
    server
    {
        listen 443;

        resolver 1.1.1.1;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
        proxy_timeout 15s;

        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8443;
        ssl_preread on;
    }
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8443;
        location / {
            proxy_pass <my backend>;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

In my stream block i can see the correct value of `remote_addr`

But in http i am getting `127.0.0.1` which is expected.

I checked other variables which i could use but they were empty like `http_x_forwarded_for` `proxy_protocol_addr`